# Maximum Collatz length in Python, but output is not correct

Tags: python, loops, collatz

This is my first time posting to Stackoverflow.

I'm trying to solve this problem here: https://codingbat.com/prob/p270692?parent=/home/konstans@stuy.edu/all

> When looking at all hailstone sequences from 1 to z, maxHail(z) will return the starting number that creates the longest sequence. In other words, maxHail(n) looks at hailLen(1), hailLen(2) ... hailLen(n) and returns the number from 1-n that had the largest hailstone sequence. You should look at the hailLen() problem before working on this. You should use your solution from the hailLen() problem. ( http://codingbat.com/author/p264289 ) since hailLen(3) is larger than the hailLen of 4 or 5, maxHail of 3,4,5 all return 3. Since 6 has a longer sequence, maxHail(6) gives us 6. remember: Use the hailLen function you already wrote!

Here's my code and the output:
[image]

However, I'm not sure where this goes wrong - I checked line-by-line and couldn't see anything wrong. Could anyone help me fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Please, paste your code in question between the ``` ``` sticks so we could interact with it

Comment: And there is no definition of hailLen task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what is wrong - hailLen returns lenght of sequence and the question is about index for which the sequence is the longest. Just store it in variable

```
if (res := hailLen(i)) > counter: # it's python 3.8 syntax
    counter = res
    index = i
return index
```